# Start ffmpeg sound recording at system start doesn't work

Tags: python, ffmpeg, audio-recording

I made a python script to record sound at System boot, but it doesn't work. I've tried using crontab and systemd but it doesn't work. If I start the program manually it works out fine.

```
#!/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import subprocess
import os
import signal
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
print("Started Sound_Recorder_ULtimate_Control")
p = None
while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if GPIO.input(24) == 1:
            if p is None:
                print("Preparing to recorde")
                today = datetime.datetime.now()
                time1 = "{}.{}.{}_{}:{}:{}".format(today.day , today.month, today.year, today.hour, today.minute, today.second)
                # Aufname starten
                command = "sh -c 'ffmpeg -f pulse -nostdin -i alsa_input.usb-FuZhou_Kingwayinfo_CO._LTD_TONOR_TC30_Audio_Device_20200707-00.mono-fallback /home/pi/sound_recorder/Recordes/'" + time1 + ".mp3"
                print(command)
                #subprocess.Popen(command)
                p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
                print("Recording...")
                GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(2)    

            else:
                print("Terminate")
                os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
                GPIO.output(23, GPIO.LOW)
                p = None
                time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't enough information to allow a diagnosis.

Comment: How are you starting it? From a systemd service? If so, check journald to read the logs.

Comment: (also, the way you're starting the command is **ridiculous**; using `shell=True` adds _one_ `sh -c`, then you're adding a _second_ `sh -c` explicitly... but there's no good reason to use any shell at all in the first place!)

Comment: (without a shell, you'd want `command = [ 'ffmpeg', '-f', 'pulse', '-nostdin', '-i', f'alsa_input.usb-FuZhou_Kingwayinfo_CO._LTD_TONOR_TC30_Audio_Device_20200707-00.mono-fallback /home/pi/sound_recorder/Recordes/{time1}.mp3' ]`)

Comment: Anyhow -- once you're reviewed the logs in the journal, [edit] the question with the specific exception thrown. If it turns out that the Python worked fine and you have an ffmpeg failure (maybe because the USB audio device isn't available yet), it might be worth factoring Python out of the question altogether.

Comment: ...btw, you can tell systemd to start a service only after a given piece of hardware is available. That _might_ be what you need to do here.